# Spring change file content

Tags: xml, spring, file, spring-mvc, resources

In my Spring Boot application, I want to fill my file with values from my POST REQUEST @RequestBody Parameters. For Example, I have file with several lines and on unknown line I have <parameters> which conatins: `<firstParameter>value<firstParameter>`

`<secondParameter>value<secondParameter>`

`<thirdParameter>value<thirdParameter>`

and in my POST Request I got parameters object with 3 fields:

`firstParameter="firstParameter",`

`secondParameter="secondParameter",`

`thirdParameter="thirdParameter"`

I'm trying to find the easiest way to solve this problem. I've read many articles but couldn't find appropriate one. Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate more on your problem? Are you trying to modify a file on the server using a post? If that's the case then you should know that how you deploy your application (tomcat, java app, etc)will affect how you access the files on the server.

Comment: It's spring boot app thats runs on localhost, file is in src/main/resources folder. I have implemented this way: read all lines. if(currentLine equals "<firstParameter>value<firstParameter>" then change this line to "<firstParameter>{value from RequestBody}<firstParameter>", but I don't like this solution. Maybe there should be direct way to find {value} and change it with real value. And not to read all the lines from file.

Comment: The solution you described is a straightforward and okay-to-go solution. How do you magically find the field "n" from a file in ur application, match it with the fields sent from the client, and update it....!? If you can explain more about what direct solution you are brainstorming then we can help more.